# IIS - ProviderIncompatibleIssue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis

I make the MVC project in Visual Studio and been testing it on Visual Studio Development Server. Last week I completed project and deployed to MS Server 2003 with IIS 6.0 which caused problem with the routing. Because I don't have a constant access to the server I set up IIS 7.5 on my pc and try to run it. Unfortunately it fail on first access to db with ProviderIncompatibleException and 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.' in InnerException. I understand that this is login issue to db. Is it anything in IIS or Visual Studio that I need to set up?

My connection string:

```
<add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=ukac-sql-01;Initial Catalog=MAS;Integrated Security=True" />
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does the identity that the application pool is running under have permission to access the db?

Comment: I use defaultAppPool with Identity - AppicationPoolIdentity